# SwiftUI: remove the space on List view left and right?

Tags: listview, swiftui

I have the following list view:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List(items) { item in
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView(item: item)) {
                Text("\(item.name)")
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
        .navigationBarTitle("Title")
    }
}
```

Shows up like this:

[image]

I want the cells to stick to the very left of the screen and make the padding on their left 0.

I also want the right padding to be 0...

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally found a built in way of doing this without having to hard code numbers. I spent some time digging around the documentation and found this, `listRowInsets`:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
extension View {

    /// Applies an inset to the rows in a list.
    ///
    /// Use `listRowInsets(_:)` to change the default padding of the content of
    /// list items.
    ///
    /// In the example below, the `Flavor` enumeration provides content for list
    /// items. The SwiftUI ``ForEach`` structure computes views for each element
    /// of the `Flavor` enumeration and extracts the raw value of each of its
    /// elements using the resulting text to create each list row item. The
    /// `listRowInsets(_:)` modifier then changes the edge insets of each row
    /// of the list according to the ``EdgeInsets`` provided:
    ///
    ///     struct ContentView: View {
    ///         enum Flavor: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    ///             var id: String { self.rawValue }
    ///             case vanilla, chocolate, strawberry
    ///         }
    ///
    ///         var body: some View {
    ///             List {
    ///                 ForEach(Flavor.allCases) {
    ///                     Text($0.rawValue)
    ///                         .listRowInsets(.init(top: 0,
    ///                                              leading: 25,
    ///                                              bottom: 0,
    ///                                              trailing: 0))
    ///                 }
    ///             }
    ///         }
    ///     }
    ///
    /// ![A screenshot showing a list with leading 25 point inset on each
    ///  row.](SwiftUI-View-ListRowInsets.png)
    ///
    /// - Parameter insets: The ``EdgeInsets`` to apply to the edges of the
    ///   view.
    /// - Returns: A view that uses the given edge insets when used as a list
    ///   cell.
    @inlinable public func listRowInsets(_ insets: EdgeInsets?) -> some View

}
```

So then changing my code to this:

```
var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(sctions) { section in
                
                Section(header: Text(section.name)
                            .border(Color(.red))
                            .listRowInsets(.init(top: 0,
                                                 leading: 0,
                                                 bottom: 0,
                                                 trailing: 0))) {
                    
                    ForEach(section.items) { item in
                        Text("\(item.name)")
                            .listRowInsets(.init(top: 0,
                                                 leading: 0,
                                                 bottom: 0,
                                                 trailing: 0))
                            .border(Color(.green))
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
        .navigationBarTitle("Title")
    }
}
```

Gives me this result:

[image]

Interestingly enough, `listRowInsets` works on the "cell", but also on the section header, which I then got stuck on. I wanted the section header to also go to the edges and it was not originally.

Hope this helps somebody else.

Comment: I also just found this. https://programmingwithswift.com/swiftui-list-remove-padding-left-and-right/

Answer (score 0):

I think there are various ways for that.

1. `.frame()`
2. `.offset()`
3. custom `ScrollView()` (However, there is no unique feature of list)

In the example code below, I gave an extra width in `.frame()`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var items = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(items, id: \.self) { item in
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("")) {
                    Text("\(item)")
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .navigationBarTitle("Title")
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width + 25)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

---

In the example code below, I gave an extra width in `.offset()`
But in this case, the space on the right side

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var items = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(items, id: \.self) { item in
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("")) {
                    Text("\(item)")
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .navigationBarTitle("Title")
            .offset(x: -10)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I saw options like that on stack I think, but, they assume you know the amount to frame or offset by.... Seems a hack? why 10? why 25?...

Comment: @zumzum You have to predict it(this is like adding padding) and if you want responsive for all types of iPhones, you should use a GeometryReader.